# Allow unsigned repository installation in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt, repository

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop and I'm trying to install the [OneDrive Free Client](https://github.com/skilion/onedrive) to synchronize my OneDrive on my laptop. But when I try to use the commands in the Readme, it won't install because the repo is unsigned. I tried to use the `--allow-unauthenticated` option everywhere it could go, but it still continues to fail and repeat the same error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The 'skilion' client was abandoned in 2018, and all development moved here: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive

To install the client correctly on Ubuntu you have 2 options:

1. If using Ubuntu 18.x and below - compile from source
2. If using Ubuntu 19.x and above - Use the Ubuntu PPA

Do not install the client from 'Universe' as this will install old versions of the client.

**To compile from source:**

1. Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt install build-essential libcurl4-openssl-dev libsqlite3-dev pkg-config git curl
```

2. Install the compiler

```
curl -fsS https://dlang.org/install.sh | bash -s dmd
```

3. Activate the compiler

```
source ~/dlang/dmd-2.093.1/activate
```

4. Clone the repo

```
git clone https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive.git
```

5. Build the client

```
cd onedrive; ./configure; make clean; make;
```

6. Install

```
sudo make install
```

**To install using the Ubuntu PPA**

1. Add the Ubuntu PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yann1ck/onedrive
sudo apt-get update
```

2. Install 'onedrive' from the Ubuntu PPA

```
sudo apt install onedrive
```

For further details refer to:

- Install Guide: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/INSTALL.md
- Usage Guide: https://github.com/abraunegg/onedrive/blob/master/docs/USAGE.md

For issues or support, open an issue ticket on GitHub